# How to select multiple images from gallery using Espresso?

Tags: android, mockito, android-testing, android-espresso, android-uiautomator

As I read in the doc says that **Espresso dont have access to outside apps** like camera, gallery but in my app **I want to test adding images from gallery and take pictures from camera and add it.**

I heard about **UiAutomator** but it's only supports **API 18+**, my app uses **API 14** and above.

- **Now how can I test adding multiple images from gallery and adding pictures taken from camera?**
- **I heard about Intento but dont know how to use it and what it does exactly?** I guess it mock's intent results.

Answer (score 1):

You can set different minSdk for your test module. in ..androidTest/ folder create a AndroidManifest.xml file with content of :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="your.app.package">

    <uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.test.uiautomator.v18"/>
</manifest>
```

And now when you perform gradle sync with dependency to uiautomator it should work.